# Why aren't time stamped based concurrency control protocols used more extensively?

Tags: database, database-concurrency, database-theory

As a database theoretic concept I've been a big fan of time stamped based concurrency control protocols since I first learned about them.  I've noticed they don't seem to be used much.  Why is that?  Or am I just wrong?

Edit: I mean timestamped data items with read and write time stamps and timestamped transactions with fixed timestamp order similar to what is described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp-based_concurrency_control

Comment: Where/Which database(s) you checked? It will be helpful if you can provide some case examples. :)

Comment: You mean like the way PostgreSQL works? Or something else?